# Is there still a contract size limit?

Tags: contract-deployment

I have a contract on chain and the deployed bytecode is 36.201KB, but EIP 170 limited the contract size to 24.576KB. Can anyone tell me how I was able to deploy a 36.201KB contract? https://etherscan.io/address/0x8c4317745f185534d645bff2b5e648c1d211edf5#code

Is there still a 24.576KB limit specified in EIP 170 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the deployed byte code on Etherscan, it appears to be 18099 bytes long (36198 hexadecimal characters).

Comment: Ah I must be calculating the size wrong - apparently counting each hex character as a byte. How did you get 18099?

Comment: I just copy/pasted the byte code from the page you linked to.

Comment: @pizzarob
2 hex = 1 byte so divide 36198 by 2 = 18099 (size in bytes)